# React components rendering incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react project, a recipe box, which includes the ability to open a recipe and add/delete ingredients. Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/m9r10ohg/). You can click the recipe name to open the recipe. There is an edit button which reveals the delete button and gives the option to change the name of the ingredients. When the 'delete ingredient' button is pressed, the last ingredient appears to always be deleted, regardless of which ingredient is selected, but when the 'done' button is clicked and the editable input boxes change back to text, the correct change is shown, the proper ingredient deleted and the last ingredient remains. Though this works functionally, it's obviously not very UI friendly, and I wondered why this was happening. Any help would be great.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/m9r10ohg/1/)

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const array = this.props.update;
   let booleanButton = null;
   if (this.props.ingr) {
////////////////////////////
// here is the button's JSX
    booleanButton = <button onClick=
    {this.props.handleDeleteIngredient.bind(this, array)}>delete 
    ingredient</button>;
///////////////////////////
   }
 return (<div><form><input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.text} 
   onChange={this.props.onChange.bind(this, array)} /></form>{booleanButton}
  </div>)
  }
}
```

And the handler:

```
handleDeleteIngredient(data, e ) {
  var key = data[2];
  var ingrs = this.state.ingrs;
  ingrs.splice(key, 1);
  this.setState({ingrs:ingrs});
}
```

Comment: you need to collect all your data into the state object inside the constructor method

Comment: all of the data is stored in state already

Comment: Sorry about that i didn't see the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is quiet confusing, and according the your fiddle code I think your problem is caused by not setting a good key for your list Item.
from what it looks in this line, you don't have a key={ingrs[i]} props, try set it to id see it will work, but making ingrediant name as key is probably not a good idea, try to give an actual id.

```html
ingrList.push(<Input key={ingrs[i]} handleDeleteIngredient={this.handleDeleteIngredient.bind(this)} id={id}  update={[this.props.objectIndex, "ingrs", i]} onChange={this.onInputChangeIng.bind(this)} text={ingrs[i]} />);
```

Comment: I'm sorry that the description was confusion, you can click the recipe name to open it. I know that the `key` props helps react render to the DOM more effectively, but your solution didn't work :(

Comment: Ok, it's still a key problem, I just didn't look too close to the code since I didn't know how it works, put a unique key at very outer element in your case <Input> will make it work, I edited my answer.

Comment: awesome, thank you! how does adding the `key` prop work? and what does the `id` prop do?

Comment: I'm not sure if react component has id prop. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. just make sure you always always have a good unique key in every list elements